# Gitlab separate container registry per environment

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Since we have multiple environments from the change management process, I would like to use a separate container registry per environment. Gitlab has a concept of environment where you can define different environments and later you can keep track of application versions that are deployed to each environment. However, it appears that there is no segregation of container registry per environment available and all are sharing the same one (at the project level).

Is there a clean way of segregating container registries per environment in Gitlab Container Registry or I need to come with a separate folder per environment? Obviously this approach will be very error-prone and someone may accidentally push something to the fold of production and the image end up deploying in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the environment consent you wrote about
but i hope this will help.

You can separate them in different repos

This is the default registry
`registry.gitlab.com/username/project`

You can do
`registry.gitlab.com/username/project/prod`
`registry.gitlab.com/username/project/dev`

Or 
`registry.gitlab.com/username/project/prod/project`
`registry.gitlab.com/username/project/dev/project`

[Here how my project registry looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW9Gu.png)

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yeah. This is exactly how I put it as an interim solution. However, the challenge is one point of having a sperate registry is also to ensure accidentally nobody pushes an image to production/staging without going through the entire process.